# Rupee symbol without using image, javascript, or font

Tags: html, css

I tried following code to print rupee symbol;

```
Firefox : <rs><span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-5px">_</span>&#2352;</rs>
<br />
IE7 : <rs><span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-4px">_</span>&#2352;</rs>
<br />
Chrome : <rs><span style="position:absolute;margin-top:-10px">_</span>&#2352;</rs>
```

But due to brwser incopatability of `margin-top`, I can not accept it as final solution. I also had tried border-bottom with 25% width for `<span>`. But it dint work since  needs to be absolute. And in this condition it takes 25% page height.

```
<rs><span style="position:absolute;border-bottom:1px solid;height:25%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&#2352;</rs>
```

Please suggest a solution as css properties which are multi browser compatible and dont require js,image or font.

*I dont want anything in pixels since it'll require changes every time when i need to resize rupee symbol.

Comment: I cant understand why you are saying no to "font" 
I think using font icons from http://fontawesome.io/icons/ is the best solution for cross browser compatibility and it is also very easy to use.

Comment: @Sagar This question is more than 3 years old, That time Rupee symbol was new in the market and its unicode was not supported by many browsers. I said no to font since font were getting requested at least once on page load which was consuming bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the Rupee character code itself: `&#8377;`?

₹